# Python subprocess .check_call vs .check_output

Tags: python, bash, ssh, subprocess

My python script (python 3.4.3) calls a bash script via subprocess:

```
import subprocess as sp
res = sp.check_output("bashscript", shell=True)
```

The **bashscript** contains the following line:

```
ssh -MNf somehost
```

which opens a shared master connection to some remote host to allow some subsequent operations.

When executing the python script, it will prompt for password for the `ssh` line but then it blocks after the password is entered and never returns. When I ctrl-C to terminate the script, I see that the connection was properly established (so `ssh` line was successfully executed).

I don't have this blocking problem when using `check_call` instead of `check_output`, but `check_call` does not retrieve stdout. I'd like to understand what exactly is causing the blocking behavior for `check_output`, probably related to some subtlety with `ssh -MNf`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`check_call()` returns as soon as `/bin/sh` process exits without waiting for descendant processes (assuming `shell=True` as in your case).

`check_output()` waits until all output is read. If `ssh` inherits the pipe then `check_output()` will wait until it exits (until it closes its inherited pipe ends).

`check_call()` code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys
import time

start = time.time()
cmd = sys.executable + " -c 'import time; time.sleep(2)' &"
subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
assert (time.time() - start) < 1
```

The output is not read; `check_call()` returns immediately without waiting for the grandchild background python process.

`check_call()` is just `Popen().wait()`. `Popen()` starts the external process and returns immediately without waiting for it to exit. `.wait()` collects the exit status for the process -- it doesn't wait for other (grandchildren) processes.

If the output is read (it is redirected and the grandchild python
process inherits the stdout pipe):

```
start = time.time()
subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
assert (time.time() - start) > 2
```

then it waits until the background python process that inherited the pipe exits.

`check_output()` calls `Popen().communicate()`, to get the output. `.communicate()` calls `.wait()` internally i.e., `check_output()` also waits for the shell to exit and `check_output()` waits for EOF.

If the grandchild doesn't inherit the pipe then `check_output()` doesn't wait for it:

```
start = time.time()
cmd = sys.executable + " -c 'import time; time.sleep(2)' >/dev/null &"
subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
assert (time.time() - start) < 1
```

Grandchild's output is redirected to `/dev/null` i.e., it doesn't inherit the parent's pipe and therefore `check_output()` may exit without waiting for it.

Note: `&` at the end which puts the grandchild python process into background. It won't work on Windows where `shell=True` starts `cmd.exe` by default.

Comment: Superb, thank you for this detailed explanation @jfs