# subprocess with timeout: What to do after TimeoutExpired Exception?

Tags: python, shell, timeout, subprocess

subprocess timeout=SECONDS don't work for me if I follow the advice of the python docs:

```
# copy+pasteable snippet :-)
import subprocess32 as subprocess
import datetime

now=datetime.datetime.now()
pipe=subprocess.Popen('sleep 5', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    pipe.communicate(timeout=1)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired, exc:
    time_delta=datetime.datetime.now()-now
    print(time_delta)
    assert time_delta<datetime.timedelta(seconds=3), time_delta
    pipe.kill()
    outs, errs = pipe.communicate()
    time_delta=datetime.datetime.now()-now
    print(time_delta)
    assert time_delta<datetime.timedelta(seconds=3), time_delta
    print('OK')
```

The docs advice to use pipe.kill() and pipe.communicate() after TimeoutExpired: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

It does not work for me. The second `communicate()` does not return soon.

Exception:

```
0:00:01.001234
0:00:05.002919
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/src/test_timeout.py", line 16, in <module>
    assert time_delta<datetime.timedelta(seconds=3), time_delta
AssertionError: 0:00:05.002919
```

If I use `['sleep', '5']` instead of `shell=True`, then it works.
If I don't supply `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, then it works, too.

I guess the shell does not react on the pipe.kill().

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general pattern: catch `TimeoutExpired`, kill started processes, call `.communicate()` again is correct.

The issue is that `pipe.kill()` in your code kills only the shell while its descendant processes such as `/bin/sleep` may continue to run. See  [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279).

Note: if desired; it is not necessary to wait for grandchildren processes. See [Python subprocess .check_call vs .check_output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36169571/4279).

Comment: Thank your the link to the other StackO question. I marked my question as an duplicate.