# subprocess: Can communicate() timeout, given that wait() terminates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Is it possible for `Popen.communicate(timeout=2)` to raise `TimeoutExpired`, even though I am asserting that `Popen.poll() is not None` and `Popen.wait(2)` does *not* throw an exception?

Edit: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) suggest to use the following snippet:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
```

but this will just raise `ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] No such process`. Which makes sense because I've already terminated the process via `poll` and `wait`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible if the child spawns its own subprocesses. `Popen.communicate()` may return much later than `Popen.wait()` which waits only for the child. See [Python subprocess' `check_call()` vs `check_output()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36169571/4279).

Note: `proc.kill()` might not kill the whole process tree. See [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279).