# Subprocess timeout failure

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to use a timeout on a subprocess

```
 from subprocess32 import check_output
 output = check_output("sleep 30", shell=True, timeout=1)
```

Unfortunately, whilst this raises a timeout error, it does so after 30 seconds. It seems that check_output cannot interrupt the shell command.

What can I do on on the Python side to stop this? 
I suspect that subprocess32 fails to kill the timed out process.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`check_output()` with timeout is essentially](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/268c20ef6920651b440f827a93efa8887dcba99f/Lib/subprocess.py#L604-L610):

```
with Popen(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs) as process:
    try:
        output, unused_err = process.communicate(inputdata, timeout=timeout)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        process.kill()
        output, unused_err = process.communicate()
        raise TimeoutExpired(process.args, timeout, output=output)
```

There are two issues:

- [the second] `.communicate()` may wait for descendant processes, not just for the immediate child, see [Python subprocess .check_call vs
  .check_output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36169571/4279)
- `process.kill()` might not kill the whole process tree, see [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279)

It leads to the behaviour that you observed: the `TimeoutExpired` happens in a second, the shell is killed, but `check_output()` returns only in 30 seconds after the grandchild `sleep` process exits.

To workaround the issues, kill the whole process tree (all subprocesses that belong to the same group):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired
from time import monotonic as timer

start = timer()
with Popen('sleep 30', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid) as process:
    try:
        output = process.communicate(timeout=1)[0]
    except TimeoutExpired:
        os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGINT) # send signal to the process group
        output = process.communicate()[0]
print('Elapsed seconds: {:.2f}'.format(timer() - start))
```

#### Output

```
Elapsed seconds: 1.00
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this a bug in subprocess? Or is this behaviour deliberate? It's not what I expected.

Comment: I don't know. The current docs do not indicate that descendant processes that inherited the pipe are waited too (until EOF)—the docs mention only the child process. The behavior (`timeout` is not respected if descendant processes inherit the pipe) is not obvious; the docs could be updated—you could open a new issue on http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: not sure why, but your os.killpg() seems to kill a lot more than what I expected. If I run it through a ssh connection, the connection breaks when that method is called...

Comment: Can you explain what the significance of `preexec_fn=os.setsid` is?  It doesn't seem to be supported on Windows.  Can this just be omitted on Windows and expect the same result?  EDIT: actually, `os.killpg` also doesn't exist on Windows.  I guess this answer is Unix-only.

Comment: @cowlinator yes, the answer is Unix-only.

Answer (score 4):

**Update for Python 3.6**.

This is still happening but I have tested a lot of combinations of `check_output`, `communicate` and `run` methods and now I have a clear knowledge about where is the bug and how to avoid it in a easy way on Python 3.5 and Python 3.6.

My conclusion: **It happens when you mix the use `shell=True` and any `PIPE` on `stdout`, `stderr` or `stdin` parameters** (used in `Popen` and `run` methods).

Be careful: **`check_output` uses `PIPE` inside**.
If you look at the code inside on Python 3.6 it is basically a call to `run` with `stdout=PIPE`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ae011e00189d9083dd84c357718264e24fe77314/Lib/subprocess.py#L335

So, to solve @innisfree problem on Python 3.5 or 3.6 just do this:

```python
check_output(['sleep', '30'], timeout=1)
```

And for other cases, just **avoid mixing `shell=True` and `PIPE`, keeping in mind that `check_output` uses `PIPE`**.

Comment: You don't need the shell to get the issue. Other processes may create their own child processes too. For example, a python script can create their own child processes using the subprocess module without starting a shell. `shell=False` can fix the specific example from the question but it is more than likely that the actual command is not just "sleep 30" and therefore `shell=False` won't fix the timeout issue.